# Trouble accessing the OS X Lion web server from other device

Tags: macos, apache, webserver, web-sharing

I'm developing a web app for mobile phones. To easily get a feel of how it is to use, I simply copied the app into `~/Sites` (after enabling web sharing in the `System Preferences`).

Navigating to `http://localhost/~username/myapp.html` works perfectly. But if I do an `ifconfig` to get my IP address and navigate to the URL from my iPhone (substituting localhost with the IP address), I get an `Error 404`. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put it in the

~/Sites

Folder then you have to navigate to

192.168.0.1/~USERNAME

Where you substitute your IP address and the username that belongs to the ~/Sites folder you copied your web app to.

To get it to just recognize the IP address without the username subfolder put it here:

/Library/Webserver/Documents

EG *NOT* the library folder in your home folder but the library folder in the root of the hard drive.